# Data is not passed to controller as object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class like so:

```
public class EditItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? UserAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller like so:

```
public ActionResult EditItem(EditItem item)
{
    var im = new ItemManager();
    return Json(im.EditItem(item));
}
```

In my view, I have this script with ajax post like so:

```
function EditItem(obj) {
    this.ItemId = obj.ItemId;
    this.ItemName = obj.ItemName;
    this.SerialNumber = obj.SerialNumber;
    this.BrandName = obj.BrandName;
    this.Quantity = obj.Quantity;
    this.Description = obj.Description;
    this.UserAccountId = obj.UserAccountId;
}

$('#tbl_items').on('click', '.btn_edit', function () {
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

var itemid = $tr.find('td[data-itemid]').data('itemid');
var itemname = $tr.find('td[data-itemname]').data('itemname');
var serialnumber = $tr.find('td[data-serialnumber]').data('serialnumber');
var brandname = $tr.find('td[data-brandname]').data('brandname');
var quantity = $tr.find('td[data-quantity]').data('quantity');
var description = $tr.find('td[data-description]').data('description');

var obj = {};
obj.ItemId = itemid;
obj.ItemName = itemname;
obj.SerialNumber = serialnumber;
obj.BrandName = brandname;
obj.Quantity = quantity;
obj.Description = description;
obj.UserAccountId = 0;

 edit_item(obj);
});

function edit_item(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Item")',
        data: { item: JSON.stringify(data) },  <===== This is not passed to the controller
        success: function(result) {
             alert("saved);
            } else {
                alert("false");
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

Why is my `data: { item: JSON.stringify(data) }` not accepted by my controller? This is what I get on console.log():

{"ItemId":4,"ItemName":"ghjk","SerialNumber":"ghjk","BrandName":"ghk","Quantity":4,"Description":"hdfh","UserAccountId":0}

The names are all the same with my model but still the controller does not accept it. I can actually manually have the controller receive differennt values but I'd like to send it as an object.

Comment: Its just `data: data,`

Comment: You need to have the verb [HttpPost] on your EditItem action in controller. And also for ajax post you need to have header content-type as application/json

Answer (score 1):

Please pass

```
data: { item: JSON.stringify(data) }
```

as `data: data`

It doesn't needs another object with property named item

And also it doesn't needs to be JSON stringified. we can directly pass the object.

Comment: This does not work - its just `data: data` - no `JSON.stringify()`!

Comment: My Bad!! the JSON.stringify() doesn't works. Updating my answer just so that later readers doesn't get confused. Thanks Stephen